# Cannot change default display manager on Mint 19 Beta

Tags: linux-mint, lightdm, display-manager, mdm

On Linux Mint 18.3, when I used to install `mdm`, the command `sudo apt install mdm` would open a prompt such as:

[image]

and I would choose the default display manager. Running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mdm` would also open the new window.

On Linux Mint 19 Beta, installing `mdm` does not open such a window. How to overcome this?

I just compared step by step on two fresh installations:

- in both cases, `lightdm` is installed default and `mdm` is not.
- with 18.3, `sudo apt install mdm` opens a new window, but not on 19 beta.

Answer (score -1):

Mint developers have added a new software package called middleman which uses the name mdm, replacing the Mint Display Manager, which is no longer available from what I've seen. Kind of a juvenile way to force people into your personal preference, but user preference no longer seems to be a priority.

Comment: I don't think so - on a Mint 19 system - `user@darkstar:~$ apt-cache madison mdm
       mdm | 0.1.3-2.1build2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages`  Change is coming from Ubuntu, not Mint.